# When segueing back to view controller in navigation controller, entire screen is blank

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

Right now, I have a view controller that is embedded within a navigation controller and that has a collectionView in it. When the user presses a button, I segue to another view controller which works fine, but when that user wants to go back to the original view controller, I have a segue but the original view controller simply shows up blank. Please help! I have attached my storyboard

[image]

Comment: Have you tried dismissing the view controller instead of using a segue?

Comment: @NeilHiddink please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You should exit segues for this purpose or else simply put the below line of code when you want to go back to previous view.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```